# NSMutableArray alloc init vs NSMutableArray array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

What is the differece between:

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
```

and

```
[NSMutableArray array]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Diference between \[NSMutableArray array\] vs \[\[NSMutableArray alloc\] init\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423211/diference-between-nsmutablearray-array-vs-nsmutablearray-alloc-init)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here in `[NSMutableArray array]`  you don't have to release `array` it will be released automatically. & if you will write `[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` you will have to release `array` so `[[NSMutableArray array]` will be equivalent to `[[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];`

Comment: I edit this , ImageList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; as ImageList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelese] ;   but it didn't work. What should be the error

Answer (score 1):

The first remains in memory until you release it, the second lasts until the end of the run loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableArray` no need to release memory and `[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` u must be release it.

Answer (score 0):

when ARC does work, you have to release objects come from methods including init,alloc,new,copy and mutableCopy, like [NSMutableArray alloc] init]. If not, the objects will be registered to autoreleasepool, like [NSMutableArray array].