# How to initialize an empty mutable array in Objective C

Tags: ios, arrays, cocoa, object

I have a list of objects (trucks) with various attributes that populate a tableview. When you tap them they go to an individual truck page. There is an add button which will add them to the favorite list in another tableview. How do I initialize an empty mutable array in Cocoa?

I have the following code:

```
-(IBAction)addTruckToFavorites:(id)sender:(FavoritesViewController *)controller
{
    [controller.listOfTrucks addObject: ((Truck_Tracker_AppAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).selectedTruck];

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't make the controller's mutable array public like that. The controller should only make an immutable array available to other objects; for adding a new truck, you should add a method to the controller that does that. Then, instead of getting the `listOfTrucks` and directly changing it without the controller's knowledge, you tell the controller to make the change.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Update:**

With new syntax you can use:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray new];
```

**Original answer:**

for example:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423211/difference-between-nsmutablearray-array-vs-nsmutablearray-alloc-init) you find out why (difference between class and instance method)

Comment: Even if the array is initially empty, if you know that you will be putting a certain number of objects into it, `initWithCapacity:` may make that population step faster (because the array may initially create its backing storage with space for that many objects).

Comment: Moreover, autorelease is not the evil that some people make it out to be. There's nothing wrong with `[NSMutableArray array]`; it's just not appropriate for this case, assuming that the controller will assign the new array directly to its private `_listOfTrucks` instance variable.

Answer (score 11):

Basically, there are three options:

**First**

```
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

**Second**

```
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];
```

**Third**

```
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also initialize in this way

Another way for **Objective C** apart from the answer of @NSSam

```
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [@[] mutableCopy];
```

**For Swift**

```
let myArray = NSMutableArray()
```

OR

```
let myArray = [].mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this way to initialize an empty mutable array in Objective C:

```
NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

`listOfTrucks = [NSMutableArray array];` gives you a new mutable array.

Answer (score 0):

In modern Objective - C it could be even more shorter:

```
NSArray *array = @[];
```

Comment: This doesn't create a *mutable* array.