# what is the difference between these two statement?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between [NSMutableArray array] vs [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423211/difference-between-nsmutablearray-array-vs-nsmutablearray-alloc-init)

```
NSMutableArray* test = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* test1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to release `test` (as you didn't allocate it), but you do need to release `test1` (as you allocated it) (assuming no ARC involved).

The method `[NSMutableArray array]` already returns an `autorelease`ed array.

Answer (score 0):

`test` is autoreleased. That means that it has been added to the current autorelease pool, and when the pool is drained (typically, when the current run loop ends) it will be sent a release message. If no one else has sent it retain, the memory can be freed at that point.

`test1` is not, and has an effective retain count of +1. Your responsibility to release, or you'll leak the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a static method of `NSMUtableArray` class, which return an initialized and autorelized array.
In the second statement you allocate and initialize it by hand

Answer (score 0):

The Relation Between the two statements :

```
[NSMutableArray array] equivalent to  [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```