# How to Create new instance without init( ) method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, initialization, nsobject

I don't know this question makes any sense. But I wanna know how we can create new instance for an `NSObject` without using any `initializers.` I have seen that I can create new `NSMutableArray` like this two ways.

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Generally I will create an instance for my `NSObject` like above using `init:` method or any other `designated initializers.` But I don't know how to create a method like below example..

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

I have seen the documentation for `NSMutableArray` and it is a subclass of `NSArray` . And also `NSArray` having a method like this to achieve an above example.

```
+(id)array;
```

But I wanna know what could the code inside of the `array:` method. Otherwise how to write a method same as like that for my own `NSObject` ?? Before vote down ask me, if you want more explanation.

Comment: That is impossible!!! always some initializers are created. Either by init, new, calloc, malloc.

Comment: This question is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423211/difference-between-nsmutablearray-array-vs-nsmutablearray-alloc-init

Comment: @PeterM I think the question you mentioned above is about memory management and ARC.

Comment: @R.A  The reason I mentioned that question is because it discusses the  difference between the two styles you mentioned - which seems to me is what you are actually asking, and as is also the answer you selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a class method on an object. [NSMutableArray array]; is creating an allocated array and returning it to you. Before arc this was important because it would also return to you an autoreleased array. But to answer your question it is behind the scenes calling an alloc/init function at some point.

Also note that "alloc" is the function to allocate the memory while the init is the function that initializes the object once it is allocated. There are other keywords that you can use to allocate memory like "copy" and "new" but I doubt that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Technically, it's a *class method*; there is no such thing as a static method in Objective-C. Also, `alloc` and `init` are not keywords -- they're method names.

Comment: Great, and while you're at it, `alloc`, `init`, `copy`, and `new` are neither functions nor keywords -- they're *methods*.

Answer (score 2):

In your SomeObject class add this class method

```
+(SomeObject)object{
 SomeObject *object = [[self alloc] init];
 //You can do something else to your object here.
 return object;
}
```

then elsewhere in your project you can just import SomeObject and do:

```
SomeObject *myObject = [SomeObject object];
```

Basically that is all NSArray is doing. If you want your own NSObject to do something like this add class method (+) that returns an instance of it's self. within that method just alloc init, do what ever else you want to that object then return it.

Comment: Sure but to create this array you just call `[NSArray array];` with no explicit init which is what he's referring to. How can you initialize something without initializing it?

Comment: NO Way to create any object without any initializer.

Comment: you forget it is also autoreleased ;)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya lol, I know... I wasn't asking the question I was saying you have to

Comment: Guys.. thanks for the answers. I saw the documentation .. [NSMutableArray array]; shows create a new array and returns.. But initWithArray: method specifies "Initializes a newly allocated array by placing in it the objects contained in a given array." So I think like array: method is not initializing.. Any idea??

Comment: as long as you use `self = [super init];` you can define your object's  init what ever you'd like i.e. `initThisReallyCoolObject` then in that method you need `+(id)initThisReallyCoolObject{ self = [super init] if(self){ //Do Something} return self;}`

Comment: But based on your question you're talking my first answer. This way you still have to alloc i.e. `SomeObject *object = [[SomeObject alloc] initThisReallyCoolObject];`

Answer (score 2):

From Apples documentation [Object Initialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html) you can infer that inititalization is not actually required when creating an object:

> Initialization sets the instance variables of an object to reasonable
>   and useful initial values

If your code does not expect initialized instance vars then technically you don't have to `init`.  However there are so many `caveats` (see the link) that in practice doing an `init` is what you should be doing.  The only exception I can think of is that you have explicitly created the object class from scratch, and not based it off something like NSObject - then you know what state everything is in.

Comment: Guys.. thanks for the answers. I saw the documentation .. [NSMutableArray array]; shows create a new array and returns.. But initWithArray: method specifies "Initializes a newly allocated array by placing in it the objects contained in a given array." So I think like array: method is not initializing.. Any idea??

Comment: It calls alloc/init internally for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate memory for the object somewhere.  In the case of `[NSMutableArray array]` it is calling +(id) array which would look something like this:

```
+(id)array
{
  return [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

It has to allocate the memory and initialize the object somewhere, but you can hide the init in a class method like what is being done in the example above.